# how to use angular js in zend framework 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zend-framework2

I am newbee to zend framework 2, and i am try to use the angular js in my project.

Actually at present, i am calling a function name in the controller like this.

```
return new ViewModel(array(

                'result' =>  $result ,

                'userData' => $row,

                'userInfo' => $userInfo,



            ));
```

and in the view page. simply i am looping the view.

```
 <?php if( $this->result )   { ?>    
    <?php foreach ($this->result as $data) {    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $data['patient_fname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['weight']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['height']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $data['bp_level_low']; ?>/<?php echo $data['bp_level_high']; ?></td>
            <!-- <td><?php echo $data['sugar_level_random']; ?></td> -->
            <td>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->url('doctor', array('action'=>'editvitalrecords', 'id' => $data['hrid'] ));?>"> Edit </a>
                <!-- |
                <a href="<?php echo $this->url('doctor', array('action'=>'deletevitalrecords', 'id' => $data['hrid'] ));?>">Delete </a> -->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

so how can i use the angular js in the above code.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Angular JS need JSON response, the simplest way is to change strategy to JSON in module config with this code

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'strategies' => array(
            'ViewJsonStrategy',
        ),
    ),
```

After that in controller you must only type

```
 return new JsonModel((array(
                'result' =>  $result ,
                'userData' => $row,
                'userInfo' => $userInfo,
            ));
```

link to nice tutorial http://hantsy.blogspot.com/2013/11/create-restful-application-with_19.html